# Get Rating from facebook pAGE

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a requirement to get ratings from public facebook pages to show on our site. For that I understand that one needs to have pageaccesstoken. But is it necessary to be an admin of the page to get pageaccesstoken in which case I will not be able to get the ratings from these public pages as I am not the admin for those pages. I just need to get the ratings. Can someone please help.

Regards
Raghav

Answer (score 1):

In order to get ratings/reviews, you do need a Page Token, that is correct. And in order to get a Page Token, you have to be Moderator or Admin of the Page. It is not possible to get the ratings/reviews from any public Page.